# How to read a text file into an array in plain C?

Tags: c, file, gcc, io

I am trying to read an entire text file into a string array in C. Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
   FILE *fp;
   long lSize;
   char *buffer;
   size_t result;
   int array_val;

   char random_word[100];

   //open fle
   fp = fopen("dictionary.txt", "rb");

   //get file size
   fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END);
   lSize = ftell(fp);
   rewind(fp);

   //allocate RAM for file
   buffer = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);

   //put file in buffer
   result = fread (buffer, 1, lSize, fp);

   srand(time(NULL));
   array_val = rand()%lSize + 1;

   random_word = result[array_val];
   return 0;
}
```

However, when I build, It doesn't work (duh) and I get these errors:

> `subscripted value is neither array nor vector: line 36`

and:

> `warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built in function 'malloc'`

Thanks all!

Comment: Please try to comment to explain the down votes so that the OP can improve what they have.

Answer (score 3):

`result[array_val]` should probably be `buffer[array_val]`, however note that this will only point to a random character, not a random word. Also, you won't be able to assign the result to `random_word` because the types are incompatible (you cannot assign to arrays). You can use `memcpy` or `strcpy` to copy a string to an array, but be careful about it, overwriting memory you don't own can result in some strange and unpredictable behaviour.

If all of the words in your file are separated by `'\n'` characters, then as a tip, you can do the following:

1. Jump to a random character in your `buffer`
2. Seek backwards to the nearest `'\n'`, or to the first character of the buffer (whichever is first), you now have a pointer to the first character of a random word,
3. Seek forwards to the nearest `'\n'`, or to the end of the buffer (whichever is first), you now have a pointer to the last character of the same word.
4. Copy into `random_word` from the first to the last character

You need to include `<stdlib.h>` in order to use `malloc`.

Comment: A little help as to how to do that please?

Answer (score 1):

`random_word = result[array_val];`

`result` is a `size_t`, which means that you can't apply indexing syntax to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a malloc() example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ewkz86d%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

First I think:
1. You use the malloc(); not need using array you can call the malloc();

Comment: Can you clarify your last sentence? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I mean：When you want to call a random number, you can dynamically call the random number stored in memory, you do not need to use arrays.this is my Proposal

Answer (score 0):

To include a correct implementation of `malloc()` you'll need to `#include <stdlib.h>`.

The error you are receiving from line `#36` is quite likely because of the way you are calculating the position of a random word, which is not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

`random_word = result[array_val];`

`random_word` is an array. Arrays cannot be assigned in C.

Answer (score 0):

You already defined `result` as `size_t`, you cannot implement in that code by indexing.

Answer (score 0):

`result` is not an array, it's just a variable of type `size_t`. `random` is the header of an array, so it cannot be changed.